# Get an input type text to set params in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Here is my view:

```
%h3
  Confirm Password:
  %input{type: 'text', name: 'password'}
= button_to 'click me', :create_user
```

The button works and hits the controller method but the only thing in params in :controller and :action. Is there a way to pass the value that user put in the textbox to the controller through the params?

Ideally, I would want to do:

```
user_password = params[:password]
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Solution

```
= form_tag :create_user, :method => :post do
  %h1
    Sign Up!
  %h3
    Email:
    %input{type: 'text'}
  %h3
    Confirm Email:
    %input{type: 'text', name: 'ans[2]', value: 'Test 2'}
  %h3
    First Name:
    %input{type: 'text'}
  %h3
    Last Name:
    %input{type: 'text', name: 'last_name'}
 %h3
    Password:
    %input{type: 'text'}
  %h3
    Confirm Password:
    %input{type: 'text', name: 'confirm'}
  %input{type: 'submit'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer would be to use a form.  If you don't want to do that you're going to need to tie a 'click' handler to the button tag to grab the values you want and pass them along.

Comment: Ill give the form a try

Comment: And I am so glad that I did! The only question now is how to have two buttons in the same form that point to different controller actions (The reason I did not want to use forms in the first place)

Comment: @JonathanO Send them to the same action and differentiate what to do by inspecting the value of the submit parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap this in a form. You are just calling a regular link now.